# Is the order of attributes in a unique index still important in Oracle 12c?

Tags: oracle, index

The internet mostly says, the order in a unique index does matter for the reasons of index search tree structure, but a colleague stated, Oracle changed that recently.

I can't find any information on such a change in the docs.

Is the order still influencing look-up speed for a unique index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not quickly test it yourself?

```
SQL> alter session set statistics_level=all;

Session altered.

SQL> create table t1 (c1, c2) as select 1, rownum from dual connect by level <= 1000000;

Table created.

SQL> alter table t1 add unique(c1, c2);

Table altered.

SQL> exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'T1');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select /*+ index(t1) */ * from t1 where c2 = 100;

        C1         C2
---------- ----------
         1        100

SQL> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(format=>'allstats last'));

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL_ID  1mu7dt5d4j8tb, child number 0
-------------------------------------
select /*+ index(t1) */ * from t1 where c2 = 100

Plan hash value: 1797320280

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name        | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers | Reads  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |             |      1 |        |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       8 |      1 |
|*  1 |  INDEX SKIP SCAN | SYS_C008413 |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       8 |      1 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("C2"=100)
       filter("C2"=100)
```

Not that bad, but using the proper order:

```
SQL> alter table t1 drop unique(c1, c2);

Table altered.

SQL> alter table t1 add unique(c2, c1);

Table altered.

SQL> select /*+ index(t1) */ * from t1 where c2 = 100;

        C1         C2
---------- ----------
         1        100

SQL> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(format=>'allstats last'));

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL_ID  1mu7dt5d4j8tb, child number 0
-------------------------------------
select /*+ index(t1) */ * from t1 where c2 = 100

Plan hash value: 2004096996

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name        | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers | Reads  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |             |      1 |        |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       4 |      2 |
|*  1 |  INDEX RANGE SCAN| SYS_C008414 |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       4 |      2 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("C2"=100)


18 rows selected.
```

Still better.

Comment: I am not clever enough, but I will become a little more clever, once I understood, what you are doing.
Thank you!

Comment: @bl4ckb0l7 what Balazs is indicating is that the query still performs better with the proper index. Note the difference between index range scan and index skip scan. Your coworker was probably referring to the skip scan introduced in (somewhat) recent versions of Oracle. So the index with the wrong field order can still be used using a skip scan, but that is less efficient than a proper index (but more efficient than no index). google skip scan for more information. (Balazs, I was hesitant to edit this in your answer as I'm not an Oracle expert myself)

Comment: @bl4ckb0l7 What I wanted to demonstrate is the difference between the 2 plans (index skip scan vs index range scan) and the amount of buffers required (8 vs 4).

Comment: I got that and didn't want to criticize any of this. I like this approach, I just wanted to point out, it didn't come to my mind to "just test it" nor did I know some of the upper commands until now! :-)
My colleagues are all like "Why do you know the difference between a range scan and a skip scan?" and I am like "How can you not?". :-D